# how to use sympy solver to solve equation generated by corresponding elements from two numpy.array?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

[image: the equation]

As I know, if the parameters in the equation are scalars, solving the equation above is implemented as:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from math import sin, cos, sqrt

# ep, t, a are in short for epsilon, theta and alpha, respectively
ep = Symbol('ep')
a = 0.4798212489019141 
t = 39.603733
solve(abs(a)-abs((ep-1)(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**2)), ep)
```

The question is, if these parameters are numpy.ndarray in 3 dimensions, how to implement this calculation?
In my case, the shape of theta and alpha is (5,277,232). So the output, ep, should also have the same shape.

Comment: What kind of solution do you get from the `solve`?  A sympy expression?  You might be able to `lambdify` it, and then use the array inputs.  That may depend on how complex the solution is.

Comment: @hpaulj I fixed some typo and added test data. However, I was puzzled that I did not get a float number as an output of solve, but a TypeError, saying "can't convert expression to float". What't wrong?

Comment: Trying to solve this for arrays of values is premature it you can't even solve it for a pair of scalars.  For this is a `sympy` problem, not a `numpy` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I pick the problem expression apart, the minimal segment that gives your error is:

```
In [13]: sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2)                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1d595e0b7cc7> in <module>
----> 1 sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py in __float__(self)
    323         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
    324             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
--> 325         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
    326 
    327     def __complex__(self):

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

The argument to `sqrt` is a sympy expression (because `ep` is a symbol):

```
In [14]: ep-sin(t)**2                                                                          
Out[14]: ep - 0.892639513815489
```

`math.sqrt` requires a float input; it can't do symbolic sqrt.

If I replace it with the sympy sqrt:

```
In [16]: from sympy import sqrt                                                                

In [17]: sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2)                                                                    
Out[17]: 
  ________________________
╲╱ ep - 0.892639513815489
```

Now if I try the whole expression:

```
In [18]: abs(a)-abs((ep-1)(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**2))    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7d1c0e01daaf> in <module>
----> 1 abs(a)-abs((ep-1)(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**2))

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

`(ep-1)` is a sympy `Add` expression.  Due to python syntax rules you can't do `(...)(...)` implying multiplication.  You have to be explicit:

```
In [19]: abs(a)-abs((ep-1)*(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**2))   
Out[19]: 
                    │         ⎛                1.89263951381549⋅ep                           
0.479821248901914 - │(ep - 1)⋅⎜──────────────────────────────────────────────────── - 0.89263
                    │         ⎜                                                   2          
                    │         ⎜⎛                         ________________________⎞           
                    │         ⎝⎝0.327659100567207⋅ep - ╲╱ ep - 0.892639513815489 ⎠           

          ⎞│
9513815489⎟│
          ⎟│
          ⎟│
          ⎠│

In [20]: solve(abs(a)-abs((ep-1)*(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**
    ...: 2)), ep)                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-944cce37e63b> in <module>
----> 1 solve(abs(a)-abs((ep-1)*(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**2)), ep)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1032             if e.has(*symbols):
   1033                 raise NotImplementedError('solving %s when the argument '
-> 1034                     'is not real or imaginary.' % e)
   1035 
   1036         # arg

NotImplementedError: solving Abs((ep - 1)*(1.89263951381549*ep/(0.327659100567207*ep - sqrt(ep - 0.892639513815489))**2 - 0.892639513815489)) when the argument is not real or imaginary.
```

Looks like you need to assign some constraints to the variable `ep`.  (I'm not enough of an `sympy` expert to do that without reading the docs.)

===

If I remove the `abs` from the expression, and refine `ep`, I get a numeric solution:

```
In [57]: expr =a-(ep-1)*(sin(t)**2 - ep*(1+sin(t)**2)/(ep*cos(t)+sqrt(ep-sin(t)**2))**2)       

In [58]: ep =  Symbol('ep', real=True)                                                         

In [59]: solve(expr, ep)                                                                       
Out[59]: [56.1511793662046]

In [60]: expr.subs(ep, _[0])                                                                   
Out[60]: -1.65423230669148e-13
```

presumably that could be repeated for other values of `a` and `t`.  The iteration method shouldn't matter, since the `solve` step will dominate that time.

Comment: There are too many errors in my code. Thanks for you comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve the above equation for pairs of a and t, you can **vectorize** your function. This allows you put in arrays with arbitrary shapes and get the function evaluated for all pairs and sorted into the right shape.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

def eps_solve(a, t):
    return a + t
eps_solve_vec = np.vectorize(eps_solve)

a = np.array([[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 4], [7, 8]]])
t = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[7, 0], [3, 1]]])
res = eps_solve_vec(a, t)
print(res, res.shape)
```